# Usable IP address to present to user

Tags: .net, networking, network-programming, usability

I'm writing a server/client distributed tool. Users will have to enter a network address at some point. I want to help my dear users determine the current IP address by telling them.

**[Update]** Client and Server run in the same network. (Or users would have access to an administrator) **[/Update]**

When I call `Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())` I get a hole bunch of entries which are all correct but not truly helpful. *By which heuristic could I select the most appropriate entry to present to the user?*

Comment: For what purpose will this IP address be used? If the client is behind a NAT (w.r.t. the server), then the client code alone may be unable to determine any useful address.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No, there is usually* no NAT in between. (* At some point my tool must focus on it's core competencies. But thanks I'll announce my hint clearly *as a hit*.)

Comment: If they're on the same network, why does the client need to be told its own address at all? - connect to the server, the server can determine the client's address.

Comment: Okay, but I want to display the servers IP adresss on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question right, you can compare `IPAddress.AddressFamily` with `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` to filter down

```
if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
```

Here is the complete code

```
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        // Local ip address
    }
}
```

`AddressFamily.InterNetwork` is the value against IPv4 addresses. In case of IPv6 you can use `AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6`. For complete listing, [please check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.addressfamily%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, that would be some filter to start with. Thank you.

Comment: I considered that too. However, I still hope for some heuristic to pick a winner address.